# Should "registrar" and "domain-registrar" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

- [registrar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registrar) × 53
- [domain-registrar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-registrar) × 44

Answer (score 1):

These tags seem like the same thing to me.  "registrar" should be sufficient in the context of this site and "domain-registrar" should be merged into it.

Edit: based on preference of commenters "domain-registrar" should be the canonical because it is clearer and not as broad.

Comment: If I *had* to state a preference it would be for `domain-registrar` just because it is very explicit. But I have no issues with using just `registrar`.

Comment: I agree, domain-registrar would be less broad.